# Efficient way of replacing values in matrix (R)

Tags: r, performance

I have a large matrix (m) and I want to replace the values in the matrix (m) that match with values stored in vectors (values_to_be_replaced) by new values (new_values). My vectors are themselves stored in a dataframe, so I can loop over the dataframe to get the vectors and then check if the matrix values are contained in the vectors. The code below does what it is supposed to do, but it is way too slow for my input data. My original data is a matrix with 4600 rows and 5900 columns and the largest of my 750 vectors contains > 6 million numbers to be compared.

I guess there is a more efficient way to do this and speed up computational time. Can someone help me to figure it out? (I have a lot of -9999 values in my matrix, so skipping them could improve computational time, but probably this is not enough)

Here is an example written in R:

```r
library("dplyr")
## setting up the input dataframe
df<-setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 50)), c("ids", "var1", "var2", "var3"))
df$ids<-seq(1, 50,1)
df$var1<-rep(c(2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5,1, 1,1, 6), each = 5)
df$var2<-rep(c(2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5,1, 1,1, 6), each = 5)
df$var3<-rep(c(2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5,1, 1,1, 6), each = 5)

##summarizing it by variables and ids
df<-df%>%
  group_by(var1, var2, var3)%>%
  summarise(ids=toString(ids))%>%data.frame()

##giving a new value by which values in matrix should be replaced
df$new_values<-c("101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106")

##setting up a matrix
m = matrix( c(16, -9999,17, -9999, 18), nrow=5,  ncol=10, byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 

##looping over dataframe
y<-0
for (i in 1:length(df$ids)) {
  values_to_be_replaced<-strsplit(df$ids[i], ",")
  values_to_be_replaced<-unlist(values_to_be_replaced, use.names=FALSE)
  values_to_be_replaced<-gsub(" ", "", values_to_be_replaced, fixed = TRUE)
  print(values_to_be_replaced)
  print(i)
  #print(length(values_to_be_replaced))
  m<-apply(m, 1:2, function(x) ifelse(x %in% values_to_be_replaced, df$new_values[i], x))
  #print(values_to_be_replaced)
  y<-y+1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you can just call out the elements that match, instead of iterating through them:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$ids)) {
  values_to_be_replaced<-strsplit(gsub(" ","",df$ids[i]), ",")[[1]]
  values_to_be_replaced<-as.numeric(values_to_be_replaced)
  m[m %in% values_to_be_replaced] <- df$new_values[i]
}
```

Comment: Thank you@StupidWolf! Your code works nicely and efficient enough for my large dataset!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language this is, but from the situation that you have described, it may be vastly more efficient to build a reverse lookup table which maps from values to "cells" in the matrix, then use that table to find the cells which need to be updated (rather than looping over all of them many times).

If your language or its standard library has a built-in implementation of something like a hashtable/hash map, use that.

After a cell in the matrix has been updated because it matches one of the "values to be replaced", can it be updated a second time because the *new* value matches a different "value to be replaced"? If so, you have to update the reverse lookup table at the same time as you update the actual matrix, otherwise you will have bugs.

It is possible to pre-process the vectors of "values to be replaced" to avoid this situation, so that once you build the reverse lookup table you can use it for the entire process without updating it. Then just discard it at the end (after you have made all the replacements). However, getting that code right will be slightly trickier than just updating the reverse lookup table together with the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Alex. The code is written in R. The values cannot be overwritten a second time, because I replace them with values between 1-750 (number of vectors) and these values are not contained in the vectors. It also does not happen in the example I gave, because the new_values are >100, while the values in the matrix are <=50.